# do-while loop unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, do-while

Im making a space invaders game using javascript. Right now im trying to adjust it so it has 2 levels in my Space Invaders game.So let me get to the point, in the console it says:

Uncaught ReferenceError: gamelevel is not defined

It also  tells me its in line 397 which is the end of my while loop where i give it a condition. I tried for hours trying to fix this problem but simply cant. I need your help guys! Thanks! Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Space Invaders</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            background: transparent;
        }

        #backgroundCanvas {
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="playerCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="enemiesCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>

    <script>

        (function() {
            do{
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var gameWonSoundCount = 0;
                var gameEndSoundCount = 0;
                var game = {};
                var gamelevel = 1;

                game.stars = [];
                game.width = 550;
                game.height = 600;
                game.images = [];

                game.doneImages = 0;
                game.requiredImages = 0;
                game.keys = [];
                game.projectiles = [];
                game.enemies = [];

                game.count = 0;
                game.division = 48;
                game.left = false;
                game.enemySpeed = 3;

                game.fullShootTimer = 10;
                game.shootTimer = game.fullShootTimer;

                game.gameOver = false;
                game.gameWon = false;
                game.gameWon2 = false;
                game.moving = false;

                game.explodeSound = new Audio("Explosion.wav");
                game.gameWonSound = new Audio("GameWon.mp3");
                game.gameOverSound = new Audio("GameOver.mp3");
                game.gameEndSound = new Audio("GameWon.mp3");
                game.shootSound = new Audio("Shoot.wav");



                game.contextBackground = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas").getContext('2d');

                game.contextPlayer = document.getElementById("playerCanvas").getContext('2d');

                game.contextEnemies = document.getElementById("enemiesCanvas").getContext('2d');

                game.player = {
                    x: game.width / 2 - 50,
                    y: game.height - 103,
                    width: 80,
                    height: 100,
                    speed: 3,
                    rendered: false
                }




                $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                    game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which] = true;

                })
                $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                    delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which];

                })

                /*
      up -38
      down-40
      left -37
      right-39
      w-87
      a-65
      s-83
      d-68
      space-32
    */
                function addBullet() {
                    game.projectiles.push({
                        x: game.player.x,
                        y: game.player.y,
                        size: 20,
                        speed: 3,
                        image: 2

                    })

                }

                function init() {
                    for (i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
                        game.stars.push({
                            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width),
                            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height),
                            size: Math.random() * 5
                        })
                    }

                    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                            game.enemies.push({
                                x: (x * 70) + (70 * x) + 10,
                                y: (y * 70) + (10 * y) + 40,
                                width: 70,
                                height: 70,
                                image: 1,
                                dead: false,
                                deadTime: 20
                            })
                        }
                    }


                    loop();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        game.moving = true;
                    }, 5000)
                }

                function addStars(num) {
                    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                        game.stars.push({
                            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width),
                            y: game.height + 10,
                            size: Math.random() * 5
                        })
                    }

                }

                function update() {
                    addStars(1);
                    game.count++;

                    if (game.shootTimer > 0) {
                        game.shootTimer--;
                    }
                    for (i in game.stars) {
                        if (game.stars[i].y <= -5) {
                            game.stars.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                        game.stars[i].y--;
                    }

                    if (game.keys[37] || game.keys[65]) {
                        if (!game.gameOver) {
                            if (game.player.x >= 0) {
                                game.player.x -= game.player.speed;
                                game.player.rendered = false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (game.keys[39] || game.keys[68]) {
                        if (!game.gameOver) {
                            if (game.player.x <= 500 - 50) {
                                game.player.x += game.player.speed;
                                game.player.rendered = false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (game.count % game.division == 0) {
                        game.left = !game.left;
                    }

                    for (i in game.enemies) {
                        if (!game.moving) {
                            if (game.left) {

                                game.enemies[i].x -= game.enemySpeed;
                            } else {
                                game.enemies[i].x += game.enemySpeed;
                            }
                        }
                        if (game.moving) {
                            game.enemies[i].y++;
                        }
                        if (game.enemies[i].y >= 670) {
                            game.gameOver = true;
                        }
                    }

                    for (i in game.projectiles) {
                        game.projectiles[i].y -= 3;
                        if (game.projectiles[i].y <= -10) {
                            game.projectiles.splice(i, 1)
                        }
                    }

                    if (game.keys[32] && game.shootTimer <= 0) {
                        addBullet();
                        game.shootSound.play();
                        game.shootTimer = game.fullShootTimer
                    }

                    for (m in game.enemies) {
                        for (p in game.projectiles) {
                            if (collision(game.enemies[m], game.projectiles[p])) {
                                game.explodeSound.play();
                                game.enemies[m].dead = true;
                                game.enemies[m].image = 3;
                                game.projectiles.splice(p, 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (i in game.enemies) {
                        if (game.enemies[i].dead) {
                            game.enemies[i].deadTime--;
                        }
                        if (game.enemies[i].dead && game.enemies[i].deadTime <= 0) {

                            game.contextEnemies.clearRect(game.enemies[i].x, game.enemies[i].y, game.enemies[i].size, game.enemies[i].size);
                            game.enemies.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }

                    if (game.enemies.length <= 0) {
                        gamelevel = +1;
                        if (gamelevel >= 3) {
                            game.gameWon = true;
                        }
                        if (gamelevel== 2) {
                            game.division = 24;// Makes the enemies go left and right faster
                            game.gameWon2 = true;

                        }

                    }
                }

                function render() {
                    game.contextBackground.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height)
                    game.contextBackground.fillStyle = "white";
                    for (i in game.stars) {
                        var star = game.stars[i];
                        game.contextBackground.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size);
                    }
                    if (!game.player.rendered) {
                        game.contextPlayer.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
                        game.contextPlayer.drawImage(game.images[0], game.player.x, game.player.y, game.player.width, game.player.height);
                        game.player.rendered = true;
                    }

                    game.contextBackground.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
                    game.contextEnemies.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
                    for (i in game.enemies) {
                        var enemy = game.enemies[i];
                        game.contextEnemies.drawImage(game.images[enemy.image], enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
                    }

                    for (i in game.projectiles) {
                        var proj = game.projectiles[i];
                        game.contextEnemies.drawImage(game.images[proj.image], proj.x, proj.y, proj.size, proj.size);

                    }

                    if (game.gameOver) {

                        var gradient = game.contextPlayer.createLinearGradient(0, 0, game.width, 0);
                        gradient.addColorStop("0", "magenta");
                        gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "white");
                        gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "black");
                        // Fill with gradient
                        game.contextPlayer.fillStyle = gradient;

                        game.contextPlayer.font = "bold 50px monaco"
                        game.contextPlayer.fillText("Game Over!", game.width / 2 - 130, game.height / 2 - 25);
                        if (gameEndSoundCount < 2) {
                            gameEndSoundCount += 1;
                            game.gameOverSound.play();
                        }
                    }

                    if (game.gameWon) {
                        var gradient = game.contextPlayer.createLinearGradient(0, 0, game.width, 0);
                        gradient.addColorStop("0", "magenta");
                        gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "white");
                        gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "black");
                        // Fill with gradient
                        game.contextPlayer.fillStyle = gradient;

                        game.contextPlayer.font = "bold 50px monaco"
                        game.contextPlayer.fillText("Game Won!", game.width / 2 - 130, game.height / 2 - 25);
                        if (gameWonSoundCount < 2) {
                            gameWonSoundCount += 1;
                            game.gameWonSound.play();
                        }

                    }

                    if (game.gameWon2) {
                        var gradient2 = game.contextPlayer.createLinearGradient(0, 0, game.width, 0);
                        gradient2.addColorStop("0", "magenta");
                        gradient2.addColorStop("0.5", "white");
                        gradient2.addColorStop("1.0", "black");
                        // Fill with gradient
                        game.contextPlayer.fillStyle = gradient2;

                        game.contextPlayer.font = "bold 50px monaco"
                        game.contextPlayer.fillText("Level 2", game.width / 2 - 130, game.height / 2 - 25);
                        if (gameWonSoundCount < 2) {
                            gameWonSoundCount += 1;
                            game.gameWonSound.play();
                        }

                    }

                }

                function loop() {
                    requestAnimFrame(function() {
                        loop();
                    });
                    update();
                    render();
                }

                function initImages(paths) {
                    game.requiredImages = paths.length;
                    for (i in paths) {
                        var img = new Image;
                        img.src = paths[i];
                        game.images[i] = img;
                        game.images[i].onload = function() {
                            game.doneImages++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                function collision(first, second) {
                    return !(first.x > second.x + second.width ||
                        first.x + first.width < second.x ||
                        first.y > second.y + second.height ||
                        first.y + first.height < second.y);

                }

                function checkImages() {

                    if (game.doneImages >= game.requiredImages) {
                        init();
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            checkImages();

                        }, 1)
                    }
                }
                game.contextBackground.font = "bold 50px monaco"
                game.contextBackground.fillStyle = "white";
                game.contextBackground.fillText("loading", game.width / 2 - 100, game.height / 2 - 25)
                initImages(["player.gif", "enemy.png", "bullet.png", "explosion.gif"])
                checkImages();
            });

            window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
                return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    function(callback) {
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                    };
            })();
    }while(gamelevel>=3)
        })();

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Putting a `$(document).ready()` call in a `do ... while` loop is not a good idea. In fact, almost everything you've got in that loop is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define gameLevel var before **do**

```
var gamelevel = 1;
do{
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var gameWonSoundCount = 0;
       var gameEndSoundCount = 0;
       var game = {};

...
```

in current version the variable is out of while() context

Comment: Omg Sorry for distruption such an easy mistake. Im really sorry

Comment: chill out - forgiven! :P

Comment: because then the body of function passed to ready() method will be fired **after** the document will be fully loaded and you do not risk calling something that is not loaded yet (like image on the page)

Comment: Oh, ok i will delete that. Sorry just one more question(im really sorry for bothering you) yea i put the variable outside and there were no errors, but when i finish killing the first batch of enemies the game.gameWon2 for some reason dosent go true, and dosent render Level 2 on the screen.

Comment: oh yup - of course you should not put it into loop - the method with a loop should be rather into read() thing - you can also delete it if it is not necessary (do not has to be in your case)

Comment: I actually want the levels, sorry i didnt comprehend you. Did you find the solution for the new problem?

Comment: Nvm i got the problem! Thank you so much sir! Ahh still have problems, the count is basically useless

Comment: Ahh still have problems, the count is basically useless , i cant loop it so it does it once and do the game level 2. Because it loops it so many times it becomes more than three making both level 2 and gameWon true. :( Help

Answer (score 1):

If `gamelevel` is declared inside your `do..while` loop, it's not accessible in the `while` part. You need to move it outside:

```
var gamelevel = 1;
do {
   ...
```

I am curious, though, why you have a `$(document).ready()` *inside* a `do..while`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Omg Sorry for distruption such an easy mistake. Im really sorry

Comment: How can i avoid that? Can i just delete the $(document).ready() and will it still work?

Comment: @ewrwr You should probably put it outside your loop instead of inside.

Comment: Just move your do while loop from outside to inside the `$(document).ready()`block